# get parent index in array

Tags: jquery, json

I have an array

```
[
{
    "code": "MENU000014",
    "syskey": 2012071310410973022,
    "description": "Jiang Nan Dim Sum & Xiao Long Bao",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "kp-1.jpg",
    "imageb": "kp-1.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menutype": 1,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": ""
},
{
    "code": "MENU000019",
    "syskey": 2012071310571230035,
    "description": "Mix &  Match Multi-flavoured Xiao Long Bao",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "",
    "imageb": "",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012071310410973022,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "é›ªç¢§é…é¦™è‰é›ªç³•"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000020",
    "syskey": 2012071310571230036,
    "description": "Immediate preparation for Jiang Nan Speciality",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "",
    "imageb": "",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012071310410973022,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "é›ªç¢§é…é¦™è‰é›ª"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000002",
    "syskey": 2012071305045623001,
    "description": "Jiang Nan Appetizer",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "kp-4.jpg",
    "imageb": "kp-4.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menutype": 1,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": ""
},
{
    "code": "MENU000024",
    "syskey": 2012111809055570004,
    "description": "Soup",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "kp-5.jpg",
    "imageb": "kp-5.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menutype": 1,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": ""
},
{
    "code": "MENU000003",
    "syskey": 2012071305062942004,
    "description": "Double-Boiled Soup",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "0207_s.jpg",
    "imageb": "0207.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012111809055570004,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "åŽŸç›…ç‚–æ±¤"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000004",
    "syskey": 2012071305080136007,
    "description": "Soup & Thick Soup",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "kp-5.jpg",
    "imageb": "kp-5.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012111809055570004,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "ç¾¹ã€‚ç”Ÿæ»šæ±¤"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000022",
    "syskey": 2012111809055570002,
    "description": "Dishes",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "kp-6.jpg",
    "imageb": "kp-6.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menutype": 1,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": ""
},
{
    "code": "MENU000001",
    "syskey": 2012071304555547001,
    "description": "Pork",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "0403_s.jpg",
    "imageb": "0403.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012111809055570002,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "è‚‰ç±»ã€‚çŒª"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000005",
    "syskey": 2012071306020332001,
    "description": "Prawn",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "0801_s.jpg",
    "imageb": "0801.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012111809055570002,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "æµ·é²œã€‚è™¾"
},
{
    "code": "MENU000006",
    "syskey": 2012071306033011004,
    "description": "Beef",
    "price": 0.0,
    "images": "0503_s.jpg",
    "imageb": "0503.jpg",
    "plucode": "",
    "style": "",
    "option": "",
    "stocksyskey": 0,
    "parentID": 2012111809055570002,
    "menutype": 2,
    "priceoperator": 0,
    "chineseDescription": "è‚‰ç±»ã€‚ç‰›"
},
```

and I have one value of array **2012071304555547001** now how can I get the index of array not the index of this value instead I need the index of array. This code is needed in jquery

Comment: Mmm nice scrollbar, how about editing your question so we can see what that code is properly?

Comment: People vote down so damn quickly. If a question is unclear, just push the OP to give more/better information instead of downvoting the question itself. Happens way too much.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a basic `for` loop? You'll need to convert `syskey` and `parentID` into strings, though -- that number is too large for (some implementations of) JavaScript to handle.

```
var index = -1;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].parentID === "2012071304555547001") { // use strings, not numbers
        index = i;
    };
};
```

Comment: +1, pretty much the answer I was about to give. I wouldn't necessarily do a type comparison though.